# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaml'?

Tags: python

I cannot seem to get pyaml working correctly - is someone able to push me in the right direction?

```
novalak@ubuntu:~/DockerApps/autocompose$ python --version
Python 3.8.10

novalak@ubuntu:~/DockerApps/autocompose$ sudo python -m pip install pyyaml
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.3.1)

novalak@ubuntu:~/DockerApps/autocompose$ env
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

novalak@ubuntu:~/DockerApps/autocompose$ sudo python autocompose.py plesk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autocompose.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sys, argparse, pyaml, docker
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaml'
```

Comment: You have pyyaml and pyaml, right? )

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you have installed `pyyaml` but you are importing `pyaml`.
Try
`pip install pyaml`

or `import sys, argparse, pyyaml, docker`

I think it will solve the problem.